# add similar text under description for all 1000 products at once

Tags: magento-1.9, products, admin-panel, attribute-set

we have 5000 products in site

we have 5 attribute-set , each attribute have 1000 products each.

**for products of only one attribute set, under description tab,
we have to add this text " color may vary as shown in above image"**

how we can achieve this for only one attribute-set products.

we don't want this text for other attribute-set products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this simply adding in product detail page..

```
    <?php $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
 $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
echo $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
if($attributeSetName=='you attibute name'){ echo $this->__('color may vary as shown in above image'); } ?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeSetId() on a non-object in  $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());

Comment: use `$_product->getAttributeSetId()`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in smae line , i am using this : $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId();

Comment: where you are placing this code?

Comment: in the end of the view.phtml file

Comment: i am using this code in below comment

Comment: $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId();
$attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
if($attributeSetName=='Mobile'){ echo $this->__('color may vary as shown in above image'); }

Comment: updated code and tested too

Comment: yes, its displaying at bottom of page. now is i have to align using css , right ?

Comment: yes not you have to do css trick ...

Comment: working fine for that attribute set.

but for other 4 attribute-set products, in view page, their respective attribute-set name is displaying at tahe end of the page.

Comment: remove echo $attributeSetName from here

Comment: if i remove that, than this text also invisible " color may vary as shown in above image"

Comment: no this different i am just checking the attribute name remove that it is not effect othere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34910/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: thanks for your support boss, you will do impossible things possible....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right your question one of the solution is that you can do this with the following steps using import/export :
 - export all your product from the wanted attribute set
 - modify the exported file with your new attribute value
 - import the file

Comment: but if i update like this, the description will lost for all 1000 products. we added different description for different products.

Comment: OK I misunderstand your quesiton, please see my edit

Comment: No problem, we will check it.